# How to avoid a duplicate row situation in mysql query below?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my tables (many to many relationship).
Their goal - to keep a history of status changes for a different requests.
(I drop from illustration all the fields what dont make sense for a question)

1.**Requests**

```
id (primary, ai) | name (varchar) | phone (varchar) | text (varchar)

1 | Maria | 9232342323 | "fist text"
2 | Petr  | 2342342323 | "second text"
3 | Lenny | 2342342323 | "third text"
```

2.**Statuses**

```
id (primary, ai) | title (varchar)

1 | New
2 | In progress
3 | Abort
```

3.**Requests_has_Statuses**

```
id (primary, ai) | requests_id (fk) | statuses_id (fk) | comment (varchar) | date (timestamp)

1 | 1 | 1 | "Fist comment about a Maria's request" | 2014-08-08 12:24
2 | 1 | 2 | "Second comment about Maria"           | 2014-08-08 12:26
3 | 1 | 2 | "Third comment about Maria"            | 2014-08-08 12: 57
4 | 2 | 1 | "First comment about Petr"             | 2014-08-08 13:23
5 | 3 | 1 | "First comment about Lenny"            | 2014-08-08 13:45
6 | 2 | 3 | "Second comment about Petr"            | 2014-08-08 14:00
```

My Goal is to have a select output like this:

```
1 | Maria | 9232342323 | "In progress" | "Third comment about Maria"  | 2014-08-08 12: 57
2 | Petr  | 2342342323 | "Abort"       | "Second comment about Petr"  | 2014-08-08 14:00
3 | Lenny | 2342342323 | "New"         | "First comment about Lenny"  | 2014-08-08 13:45
```

In simple words I need to output a current actual status and info about each request.

I was trying to do it like so:

```
SELECT r.name, r.phone, st.title, rhs.comment, rhs.date
FROM requests AS r
INNER JOIN Requests_has_Statuses AS rhs ON rhs.requests_id = r.id
INNER JOIN Statuses AS st ON rhs.statuses_id = st.id;
```

But I got an unnecessary duplication like:

```
1 | Maria | 9232342323 | "New"         | "Fist comment about a Maria's request"  | 2014-08-08 12:24
1 | Maria | 9232342323 | "In progress" | "Second comment about Maria"            | 2014-08-08 12: 26
1 | Maria | 9232342323 | "In progress" | "Third comment about Maria"             | 2014-08-08 12: 57
2 | Petr  | 2342342323 | "New"         | "First comment about Petr"              |2014-08-08 13:23
3 | Lenny | 2342342323 | "New"         | "First comment about Lenny"             | 2014-08-08 13:45
2 | Petr  | 2342342323 | "Abort"       | "Second comment about Petr"             | 2014-08-08 14:00
```

Could you help me with an advice or solution?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, join does that. Does your tables joined each other with foreign_keys?

Comment: I dont see any duplication ?  All rows are different.

Comment: You right, its not a row duplication, but result is not as i need to have (see examples above)

Comment: For Maria, how do you know that you only need the third comment?  Do you only want the most recent comment?

Comment: I added the answer to see requests_id & title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT r.id, r.phone, st.title, rhs.comment, rhs.date
FROM (
    SELECT r.id, max(rhs.date) AS date
    FROM Requests_has_Statuses AS rhs
    INNER JOIN Requests r ON r.id = rhs.requestId
    GROUP BY r.id) AS temp
INNER JOIN Requests AS r ON temp.id = r.id
INNER JOIN Requests_has_Statuses AS rhs ON rhs.requestId = temp.id and rhs.date = temp.date
INNER JOIN Statuses AS st ON rhs.statusId = st.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter to grab only the most recent status for each requestor:

```
SELECT r.name, r.phone, st.title, rhs.comment, rhs.date
FROM requests AS r
INNER JOIN Requests_has_Statuses AS rhs ON rhs.requests_id = r.id
INNER JOIN Statuses AS st ON rhs.statuses_id = st.id
where rhs.id in 
(select max(id)
from  Requests_has_Statuses AS rhs2
where rhs.requests_id = rhs2.requests_id
group by rhs2.requests_id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also please, try next query, using DISTINCT (just return one row) and at the end ordering by date (ORDER BY):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT r.name, r.phone, st.title, rhs.comment, rhs.date
FROM requests AS r
INNER JOIN Requests_has_Statuses AS rhs ON rhs.requests_id = r.id
INNER JOIN Statuses AS st ON rhs.statuses_id = st.id
ORDER BY rhs.date DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I never use JOIN when writing cross-table calculations.
Try this,

```
SELECT name, phone, title, comment, date , requests_id , title
FROM Requests Statuses Requests_has_Statuses
Where Requests.id=Statuses.id AND Requests.id=Requests_has_Statuses.id
```

***EDIT***

```
GROUP BY name;
```